# Inclusion of a small image in a heading

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I am trying, if possible, to include a small graphic at the beginning of a section or subsection heading.

Something like:

`\includegraphics[width=0.1\columnwidth]{skull.jpg}\section{Immersions, Embeddings and Virtual Subgroups}`

where the jpeg sticks to the section heading, and is not separated from it by a line break. Below is the effect on my website which I should like to reproduce in my LaTeX document. I don't needfully ask it to be *exactly* the same.

[image]

I am already aware of the answer to [this question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69922/a-small-inline-graphic) and it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: This is your first question although you're a member since a year, so [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possibility

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\bigskip

\section*{\includegraphics[width=0.1\columnwidth]{example-image} %
          \centering Immersions, Embeddings and Virtual Subgroups}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Immersions, Embeddings and Virtual Subgroups}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karl. It works. Would prefer something that could go into the toc, but this is a step in right direction!

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Do you really want the image to go in the ToC?

Comment: @karlkoeller No, you're right. I don't want the image in the toc. It will need to be an unnumbered section.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Does my answer do what you want?

Comment: Dear Karl, yes it does, thanks muchly. I have accepted it.