# Including an image in the caption of a figure

Tags: graphics, captions

I need to place a small image in the caption of an image, but I don't know how, please help.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
   \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{figure.eps}\\
\caption{Some text [SMALL IMAGE HERE].}\label{figure}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: possibly helpful: [Inclusion of a small image in a heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232123/579)

Comment: Don't use  the `center` environment inside figures: it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead.

Comment: also do not use `\\ ` before the caption

Answer (score 8):

You are probably running into problems because you have to `\protect` the image in the `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{example-image}
  \caption{Some text \protect\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image}.}
  \label{figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]